# Can I read just one value from a mySQL query?

Tags: mysql

I get a result from a mySQL query with PHP:

```
$sql_read_users = "SELECT * FROM users";
$users_result = mysql_query($sql_read_users);
```

Can I read just one row? Something as:

```
read table $users_result with key name = "John"
```

Yes, I can use a where, but I need after the select a direct read.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You could use `LIMIT` to only get 1 row.

Your question is misleading, the title reads "one value", yet your question reads "one row". Which do you require?

Comment: Thanks, but no :( I have a lot of registers. I need a direct read by values.

Answer (score 1):

It's a very trivial task. Use the `where` clausole:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE name = "John"
```

Anyway you should seriously study SQL.

Comment: Thanks but that isn't the question :P I have a lot of rows and I need a direct read. I can't close with a where clausure in my situation. Thanks :)

Comment: @user1014173 What do you mean with direct?